# Remove last Hashtag in twitter text title

Tags: php, twitter

I wants to fetch last tag in fetched twitt of my public account,

the object is looks like

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [created_at] => Tue Apr 25 16:04:57 +0000 2017
        [id] => 856901856584454144
        [id_str] => 856901856584454144
        [text] => مقتل مسؤول عن التفخيخ في فتح الشام بجرد #عرسال 
        `https://t . co/nLuASJDXgN` #لبنان `https://t . co /oMCgiTER0A`
        [truncated] => 
        [entities] => stdClass Object
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [text] => عرسال
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 40
                                        [1] => 46
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [text] => لبنان
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 71
                                        [1] => 77
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )
```

I wants to remove #hashtag from `text` attribute if it exists at the end of `text` and prepare that string in one variable. **Remeber** any other tag should remain as it is. Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: maybe try using `strrpos()` to find the last occurrence of the #?

Comment: Yes, we can use strpos($text,"#hashtag",-nagative offset) to get from end, but sometimes text end with url

Comment: You don't need the negative offset, use `strrpos` (note the extra "r") to search from the end.

Comment: Generally you have to try doing it before it will happen

Comment: Is [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ce84497eba1e3a6f44e809e4b4c03f7d134227c) what you want?

Comment: Which hashtag here in `text` attribute should be removed?